# Equivalent of Java '?' in Scala

Tags: java, scala

I have a Java method where the signature looks like:

```java
public Map<String, ?> getData() {
    return data;
}
```

I am trying to take this return value as a parameter to a Scala method:

```scala
import java.util.{Map => jMap}

def myMethod(m: jMap[String, Any]): Unit = {
  // do stuff
}

// myMethod(foo.getData())
```

With this, the compiler will complain:

```
 found   : java.util.Map[String,?0] where type ?0
 required: java.util.Map[String,Any]
```

What is `?`, and what is its Scala equivalent?

When I try:

```scala
def myMethod(m: jMap[String, ?]): Unit = {
  // do stuff
}
```

that errors with:

```
not found: type ?
```

---

Info:

```
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
Apache Maven 3.5.2 (138edd61fd100ec658bfa2d307c43b76940a5d7d; 2017-10-18T07:58:13Z)
Maven home: /usr/share/maven
Java version: 1.8.0_152, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /usr/java/jdk1.8.0_152/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "4.19.76-linuxkit", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
```

Comment: I am not totally sure but I believe `jMap[String, _]` should work. If not, then the more verbose form of an existential should `jMap[String, A] forSome { type A }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While maybe not the canonical or most efficient solution, I ended up [converting the Java map](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/conversions-between-java-and-scala-collections.html) to a Scala Map, coupled with `_` in place of `Any`.  Note that `.asScala` will produce a mutable map by default.

```scala
import scala.collection.mutable
import scala.jdk.CollectionConverters._

def myMethod(m: mutable.Map[String, _]): Unit = {
// ...

myMethod(obj.getData().asScala)
```

Note: `collection.JavaConverters._` is deprecated in favor of `scala.jdk.CollectionConverters._` since 2.13.1. [[source](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.1/scala/collection/JavaConverters$.html)]

Comment: IMO it is both canonical and efficient as they are just wrappers that forward to underlying collection. In Scala 2.13 use `import scala.jdk.CollectionConverters._`.